# Is there a way to center my tables/images in this codepen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've recently started learning how to code. I decided to make a website with all of the smash character damage values. My main setback so far is I have been unable to find a way to center all my differently sized tables and my images.

SO far I have tried to put all my tables into divs and centering them with auto margins on left and right. Additionally I have tried to flexbox my tables and center them that way but nothing seems to work. It seems to me that the only option I have left is to manually center them all but that seems like it would take forever and I am confident there is a different solution.

Here are how my tables are currently configured

```
#damagetablemario {
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:700px;
   left:80px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
#damagetablemario2 {
   display:none;
   position:relative;
   top:400px;
   left:110px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
#damagetablemario3 {
   display:none;
   position:relative;
   top:450px;
   left:540px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   margin-bottom:200px;
}
```

Here are how my tables are written in html

```
<table id = "damagetablemario">
   <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th>Forward  Tilt</th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">2.2% (punch)<br>1.7% (punch)<br> 4% (kick)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt">7%</td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt">5.5%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt">5% (foot) <br> 7% (body)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash">17.8% (fire)<br> 14.7% (arm)</td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash">14%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash">10% (front)<br> 12% (back)</td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air">8% (clean)<br> 5% (late)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air">12% (early)<br> 14% (clean)<br> 10%(late)</td>
      <td class = "Back-Air">10.5% (clean)<br> 7% (late)</td>
      <td class = "Up-Air">7%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Air">1.4% (1-5 hits) <br>
         5.5% (hit  6) <br>
         2% (landing)
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table id = "damagetablemario2">
   <tr>
      <th>Grab</th>
      <th>Pummel</th>
      <th>Forward Throw</th>
      <th>Back Throw</th>
      <th>Up Throw</th>
      <th>Down Throw</th>
      <th>Neutral Special</th>
      <th>Side Special</th>
      <th>Up Special</th>
      <th>Down Special</th>
      <th>Final Smash</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>1.3%</td>
      <td>8%</td>
      <td>11% (throw)<br>8% (collateral)</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td>5% (early)<br>4% (late)</td>
      <td>7% 1.5x <br> projectile reflect</td>
      <td>5% (hit 1)<br> 0.6% (hits 2-6)<br>3% (hit 7)</td>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>2% (early)<br>2.5% (clean)<br>3% (late)</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table id = "damagetablemario3">
   <tr>
      <th>Floor Attack Front</th>
      <th>Floor Attack Back</th>
      <th>Floor Attack Trip</th>
      <th>Edge Attack</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >7%</td>
      <td >7%</td>
      <td >5%</td>
      <td >9%</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My end goal is to have my tables centered in the middle of my screen regardless of how much text is in them.

https://codepen.io/JariCarlson/pen/pBYOjb

Comment: for that you want to remove left css

Answer (score 1):

I see most of the styling in your css are done using an ID (`#`). Due to this the same set of styles are repeated multiple times which makes your CSS file larger. Better approach is to create one CLASS with all common styling and use the class name multiple times in your HTML. This way amending your styles/maintaining will be very simple. This is the exactly what you are facing now :)

So one way to do this is by using `grid`. By doing this there's is no need to have left margins for your tables. So

1. Remove all `left:` styling on all tables
2. Remove `display: none;` on all tables
3. If `position: absolute;` use `width: 100%;`

CSS:

```
table {
   display: grid;
   justify-items: center;
}
#damagetablemario {
   /* display:none; */ /* remove */
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%; /*Add */
   top:700px;
   /* left:80px; */ /* remove */
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
#damagetablemario2 {
   /* display:none; */ /* remove */
   position:relative;
   top:400px;
   /* left:110px; */ /* remove */
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
#damagetablemario3 {
   /* display:none; */ /* remove */
   position:relative;
   top:450px;
   /* left:540px; */ /* remove */
   border-collapse:collapse;
   margin-bottom:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `left` property to `0` and add this CSS property to your `table`

```
table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

you can also try `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use display: block; for your tables. Use display: table; remove left and set margin: auto;